# How can I change a bibliography style to control the number of authors presented?

Tags: xml, ms-word, office365, bibliography

I'd like to change the lines below of a XML Word file so it would show a single author in a citation. How can I do it? I tried to find the documentation of the Microsoft Word's Bibliography XML, but I was not successful. Any tips on what should I learn to be able to do this would also be great!

```
  <source type="Book">
    <format>{%CitationPrefix%}{%Author:1|Editor:1|Compiler:1|Title%}{, %Year%}{%YearSuffix%}{, %CitationPages:p. :p. %}{, v. %CitationVolume%}{%CitationSuffix%}</format>
  </source>
```

**The citation of the entry described below, using that XML scheme above, is (ARAÚJO, CÂMARA, *et al*., 2005). However, it should be (ARAÚJO *et al*, 2005). How can I change it?** Any suggestions of topics that I should learn to be able to solve this problem would also be great!

```
<b:Source>
<b:Tag>Pau05</b:Tag>
<b:SourceType>Book</b:SourceType>
<b:Guid>{DE34E3E5-3786-41E3-895E-99DC804C83EE}</b:Guid>
<b:Author>
  <b:Author>
    <b:NameList>
      <b:Person>
        <b:Last>Araújo</b:Last>
        <b:First>Paulo</b:First>
        <b:Middle>Fernando Vidal de</b:Middle>
      </b:Person>
      <b:Person>
        <b:Last>Câmara</b:Last>
        <b:First>Ranilson</b:First>
        <b:Middle>Monteiro</b:Middle>
      </b:Person>
      <b:Person>
        <b:Last>Peçanha</b:Last>
        <b:First>Ricardo</b:First>
        <b:Middle>Moreira</b:Middle>
      </b:Person>
      <b:Person>
        <b:Last>Barbosa</b:Last>
        <b:First>Vera</b:First>
        <b:Middle>Lúcia Aquino</b:Middle>
      </b:Person>
    </b:NameList>
  </b:Author>
</b:Author>
<b:Title>Anuário Mineral Brasileiro 2002</b:Title>
<b:Year>2005</b:Year>
<b:City>Brasília</b:City>
<b:Publisher>DNPM</b:Publisher>
<b:Volume>31</b:Volume></b:Source>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format of citations and bibliography entries in Word is controlled by the XSL style sheets in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office#\Bibliography\Style folder, where # is the Office version, not by Word's Bibliography XML file. In any event, the referencing formats are governed by the relevant organisations (though the MS implementation is generally faulty). For resources related to editing Word's XSL stylesheets, see: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=bibword

Comment: Dear macropod, thank you for your answer. These styles are indeed from bibword. I am trying to update them to fit my purposes. The point is, I could not find documentation to show me how to change the line of code. Any suggestions?

Comment: See the 'How to add "et al." to authors name in ACS' discussion on the bibword discussions page. From the discussion there, it seems you should investigate the max_number_of_persons_to_display, number_of_persons_to_display_if_more_than_max, and overflow options.